# Reformulate Absolute values in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

I did not find answer to similar question anywhere so I asking here.
I have a constraint in linear programming model:

---

$|a-b|=d+g+i~$ where 
$~a, b, d, g, i$ are binary.

---

How should I reformulate this to make it linear for my model?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all variables are binary then you can write it for instance as

$$
\begin{array}{l}
d+g+i+a-b=2z \\
d+g+i\leq 1
\end{array}
$$

where $z$ is another binary variable.

Comment: nice solution, easy to verify its validity by checking all three possibilities for $a-b$

Comment: Many thanks!  How should I introduce "z" as a variable? How to determine its value in my linear programming model?